# Create a site term column with graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to add a new column to a site using MS Graph API. I followed the docs, which shows a Text column example, and that works. When I try to add a Term column I get an invalid request. Does anyone have any insight as to what I've done wrong?

See my code below.

```
var columnDef = new ColumnDefinition
{
    DisplayName = "Tag",
    EnforceUniqueValues = false,
    Hidden = false,
    Indexed = false,
    Name = "Tag",
    Term = new TermColumn
    {
        ShowFullyQualifiedName = false,
        AllowMultipleValues = false
    }
};

await graphAPIAuth.Sites[site.Id].Columns
.Request()
.AddAsync(columnDef);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph api doesn't currently support creating columns for any type fields other than plain text, I suggest you submit [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform/label-name/Microsoft%20Graph) to add support for other types of fields, I'll upvote for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyways. I spent the better part of a day experimenting with it thinking I was doing something wrong.... at least I have an answer now. I submitted a request here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/graph-api-create-column-definition-for-additional-types/idi-p/3298786